# Why does this code cause an integer overflow?

Tags: c++, inline-assembly

I have been experimenting with basic arithmetic functions in in-line assembly everything works well except for the divide which is causing an integer overflow and I don't understand why.

Here is my code:

```
int a = 10;
int b = 2;
int c = 0;

int asmdivide(void);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    asmdivide();
}

int asmdivide()
{
    __asm

    {
        push dword ptr[a]
        push dword ptr[b]
        pop edx
        pop eax
        idiv edx // integer Overflow
        push ecx
        pop dword ptr[c]
    }
    return c;
}
```

The error that I am getting is:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x010F13EC in Divide Test.exe: 0xC0000095: Integer Overflow.
```

Comment: Have you used a debugger to step through your code to determine what each register is at each step?

Comment: Check out http://www.ragestorm.net/blogs/?p=34